# NSCollectionView on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, nscollectionview

I'm developing an iPad app and I'd like to use something like the NSCollectionView on it. There are SEVERAL 3rd party libs that do that. The problem is that none of them seem to support iOS 4.x. I really need to support this version of iOS. Does anyone knows a NSCollectionView-ish control for iOS that supports iOS 4.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used AQGridView (https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) last year in an app whose deployment target was 3.1.3 (not 3.2 as mentioned by Scott in another answer -- that's the SDK version it requires, not the deployment target) so you should be able to use it for your project.

Here's a couple of other options I am evaluating for upcoming projects:

- https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView
- https://github.com/zorn/BCCollectionView

I'm not sure what their requirements are, I've just bookmarked them for checking out. GMGridView looks nice, I like its support for full-screen paging.

This one requires ARC and so you can't use it in 4.0:

- https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/KKGridView

But it does look nice. Overall, right now, I think AQGridView is the best fit for you.

Comment: You *can* use KKGridView on iOS 4.x, ARC is not only for iOS 5.

Answer (score 1):

[AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) Supports 3.2 or greater.

Comment: When I try to compile it, I get a lot of errors because there's some code that won't work without ARC.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project